# How to separate integers from a string and convert it into a float

Tags: python

I have a column in CSV file with weights written as `"4kgs" "2.05kg" "0.35kg"`. Is there a way to convert them into float? Tried [:-2] but data is not uniform as in case of "4kgs" it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: make a list of possible texts, remove them from the string, convert. split the string based on regex for any letter that is neither a number nor a dot nor a sign +-, convert splitted texts. Thats ony 2 ways .. what ddid you try? where is your [mre] and what is the problem?

Comment: I tried to avoid regex, but if nothing else is possible I will try it

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove all non-digit/dot, then convert to `float`

```
import re

float_only_pattern = re.compile("[^0-9.]")
values = ["4kgs", "2.05kg", "0.35kg"]
results = [float(float_only_pattern.sub("", value)) for value in values]
print(results)  # [4.0, 2.05, 0.35]
```

Or use `rstrip` to remove the chars that can be at the end of the string

```
values = ["4kgs", "2.05kg", "0.35kg"]
results = [float(value.rstrip("kgs")) for value in values]
```

---

For a `pandas.Series`

```
import pandas as pd

values = pd.Series(["4kgs", "2.05kg", "0.35kg"])
values = values.str.replace("[^0-9.]", "").astype(float)
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if there is any alphabet, id it is alphabet, then skip it

```py
out = float(''.join([c for c in list('2.05kg') if not c.isalpha()]))
```

```
2.05
```